# Offline Image To Text Recognition (OCR) in android

Tags: android, ocr, offline

How to build the android native SDK for image to text recognition. (I have done well with some APIs from web services. But this time, I just want to make the app without any Internet Connection, no APIs, and no Web Services. Just an **offline** OCR app).
So my question here is

1. how to **crop** each and every word containing in the image?
2. how to **compare** the cropped text with the alphabets and characters?

Comment: ocr is one complex topic. if you are new to android i suggest you give it some time . if not then here is a tutorial- http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/

Comment: As @SagarNayak said, OCR is a complex topic. As part of the team that developed offline mobile OCR, I can say it took us several years. If you have a specific use case, try using one of the available OCR tools. If you want to play with it, then Tesseract might be a good choice.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I suppose to make it offline because I want to make the OCR for my native language. I will give a try with Tesseract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess u can use [Tesseract OCR Tool](https://code.google.com/archive/redirect/a/code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr?movedTo=https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftesseract-ocr), an open source alternative by Google. How to integrate that in Android is simple via Tesseract Android Tools
Have a look at the [tess-two project on github](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two), it's very easy to use and gives good OCR results

Comment: Does Tesseract support Xamarin?

Answer (score 10):

You said you didn't want to use an API, however I suggest you use the recently released OCR API by Google:
https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Just add the following line to your dependecies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.2.0'
```

Note: Upon first use it will have to download some files from a google server for it to be able to work. Make sure to add this check `.isOperational()`. Afterwards you can use it without an internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ML Kit for Image to Text Recognition:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text

Answer (score 0):

Look for "on-device optical character recognition", like [OpticMap](https://github.com/etasdemir/OpticMap)