# Read the text in an image in android without using third party service

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition, google-mlkit

hello i am developing an mobile application (android) to share medical reports. One part of the application is read the text in those reports (reports are in JPEG / image format). Since medical reports contain sensitive data i can't use a third party service to do this. **medical reports cannot be shared with a third party in any case.** This is a requirement.

is this possible to do? How can i do this? Please guide me .

Comment: You need OCR, look into Tesseract maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Offline Image To Text Recognition (OCR) in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453199/offline-image-to-text-recognition-ocr-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot do an OCR on android platform without a third party SDK. If you still want to do so, you need to design your own OCR for that which I am pretty sure is tough. I recommend you check ***Tesseract***. It is an open source OCR project that can be easily integrated with Android. 
Also check this link: [OCR in Android Application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1275580/Android-OCR-Application-Based-on-Tesseract)

Comment: Also see my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215